# Relavent to SSRS Configuration

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

i completed reporting services configuration steps,finally i give localhost/reports in the url it shows "sql server reporting services HOME" only.it does not show contents and properties tags.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what you see? (Just post a link, someone else can edit your post to embed, if needed.) Are you seeing any error, or do you see the "New Folder" button?

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy the report you have to specify target location. The report will be present here.

Answer (score 0):

that's probably just because you don't have any folders.
Should you deploy any reports and the folders will be created:

[image]